# Input/Output error while writing specific file to /media/<user>/<deviceName>

Tags: files, usb-drive, ls, media

I transferred file f to an USB and when the transfer was complete, I ejected the drive but the system showed an error. When I reinserted the drive and did **ls -l** in it, it reads

**-????????? ? ?     ?             ?            ?                   fileName**

against the file. File is not visible and I am also not able to over-write it. It can't be accessed thorugh the terminal also.

Comment: Were you writing to a USB disk drive, or a USB flash drive? If a flash drive, just reformat it and try again. Let us know. Cheers, Al

Comment: I was writing to a usb flash drive. You are right that formatting will do but I am trying to understand what actually happened?

Comment: You'll know what happened when you try to format it. If it fails, it's probably just gone bad. Cheers, Al